# Mysql update for a range of data where some number is missing from the series

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table containing 2000 rows. I have these columns

```
roll_no  entrance_date  entrance_time  entrance_center
```

The roll number is starting from 10011 to 10011704. I want to update entrance date,center, time for specific series of numbers. Suppose I want to give roll no 10011-100145 to exam center A, exam time-10.am and date 1.1.2015, where some roll numbers in the above series may missing. In that case how to write the update statement?

Answer (score 1):

use a `WHERE` clause in your `update` statement

```
UPDATE table 
SET exam_center = 'A', 
exam_time = '10:00:00', 
date = '2015-01-01' 
WHERE roll_no >= 10011 
AND roll_no <= 100145;
```

Comment: it should be `and` condition for `roll_no`. Also, try formatting your code for better readability.

Comment: how to exclude some roll no?

Comment: The UPDATE statement will update all records between the two values whether or not there are some missing roll_nos in the series.

Answer (score 1):

Use Where Clause !

```
update <tablename> set exam_center = A, exam_time = '10:00:00', date = '2015-01-01' where roll_no >= 10011  and roll_no <= 100145;
```

Comment: How to exclude some roll no from the series where you dont want to update center,time,date

Comment: if you want to exclude a roll no you can use where roll_no != <roll_no>

Comment: IS THERE ANY OTHER SYNTAX EXCEPT WHERE FOR THIS SITUATION?

Comment: you need to use where ! 
you can use WHERE  roll_no not in ('11235' , '11111', 'xxxxx').